# Text doesn't show up in render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I made an intro, but when I render it the background shows up but the text doesn't. I fear I may have messed something up in the Compositor. What could cause this?

Click all images for full size.

This is the render layers for my scene
[image: This is the render layers for my scene]

Compositor setup
[image: Compositor setup]

The render
[image: This is how it renders]

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34160)

Comment: Check your render layers; Post a screen shot if possible

Comment: You do not have enough information posted to determine what went wrong.

Comment: @Embers There are many things that could be causing what you describe. Please edit your question and add screen shots of your nodes, render layers, render settings and any information you consider relevant.

Comment: If possible, uploading your .blend is the quickest and easiest way to help us find the problem.

Comment: @Embers as cegaton said we don't have all the data in order to help you.. please edit and add more information

Comment: So I've updated it with an image. Not sure how to upload my .blend file. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Embers to upload a blend file you can use http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ copy the link and paste it on an edit in your question.

Comment: It's very hard to read from the image of the nodes that you uploaded. I can see a viewer node but do you have a **composite** node?

Comment: @cegation I put the link to the file. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Embers If my answer helped, feel free to accept it

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a *Composite* node with the same input as your *Viewer* node.

[image]

In order for anything to be composited in the *Render Image* you must have the *Composite* node, otherwise the *Compositor* is skipped entirely.